# math equation in php

Tags: php, html, math

Im trying to do simple math in php and it works for the most part but cant work out how to do power of.  For example i have

```html
<?php
//variables and result
function bmi($height, $weight) {
    $height = floatval($height);
    $weight = floatval($weight);

return 
$weight/($height*$height) ) 
}
?>
```

but instead of $height*$height, i want to use something like $height^2

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php

Comment: Thank you, i tried ** before but it wasnt working.  Must have had syntax wrong.